# Creating sqlite table columns from a list Python

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the strings in a list as the columns names in an sqllite database I am creating. I currently have the following code (using sqlalchemy):

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///strings.db')
db.echo = False
metadata = MetaData(db)
lang_array = []
lang_array.append(Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True))
for lang in lang_keys:
    lang_array.append(Column(lang, String))

strings = Table("strings", metadata, lang_array)
```

Where `lang_keys` is a list of strings. Is it possible to pass a list in the `Table` method like above? I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'schema`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append_column()` method:

```
strings = Table("strings", metadata)
for column in lang_array:
    strings.append_column(column)
```